# Why am I getting System.FormatException when adding rewrite rules to ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET Core web app and I'm trying to configure some URL rewrite rules. I want different rules for each of my environments, so in my `Startup.cs` I've added the following line:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddIISUrlRewrite(env.ContentRootFileProvider, $"IISUrlRewrite.{env.EnvironmentName}.xml")
);
```

I've then added an IISUrlRewrite.development.xml file to the root of my web project containing the following:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect extensionless URLs to lowercase" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\." negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, when I run my app an exception is thrown by the `UseRewriter` method call:

> System.FormatException: 'Could not parse the UrlRewrite file. Message:
>   'Unrecognized parameter type: 'URL', terminated at string index:
>   '13''. Line number '5': '8'.'

I'm not aware of any changes made to the structure of URL Rewrite rules in ASP.NET Core, so what is wrong with this approach? I'm running locally using IIS Express.

Comment: Try using `<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{ORIGINAL_URI}}" />`. Seems that `URL` is not recognized in `url` value as URL parameter name.

Comment: No, sorry, now the error is "'Unrecognized parameter type: 'ORIGINAL_URI'"

Comment: How about `<action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" />` as you want to enforce lowercase URL rule?

Comment: Interesting, it no longer errors, but the logic is wrong. domain.com/tEsT redirects to domain.com/e because presumably the match returns the first uppercase character and the redirect replaces this URL with this character. Thank you though, getting somewhere!

Comment: Perhaps you need to slightly change matching regex pattern such like `<match url="^([^?]*[A-Z][^?]*)(\?.*)?" ignoreCase="false" />` to detect file names. Also possibly it uses `{ToLower:{R:1}}{R:2}"` instead of `{ToLower:{R:0}}`.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. With your help I've now worked it out. Your R:0 suggestion was correct, but my condition was breaking the rule. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @tetsuya-yamamoto I've come up with a working rule to redirect URLs to lowercase, excluding paths to physical files:

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```